# c++11 regex extracting text

Tags: c++, regex

I've been banging my head on something that seems fairly simple... at first.

I'm trying to convert text manipulation that I've been doing with strstr by using regex, which seems the way to go with c++11 now. Here's a test case example:

```
<!Sometag>
// Lots of code here! (Multiline)
<Sometag!>

<!Sometag2>
// Lots of code here! (Multiline)
<Sometag2!>
```

Edit: A more explicit example.

```
/// Comments.

<!Vertex>
#version 150
/// code here!
void main()
{
 /// code here!
}
<Vertex!>

/// Comments.
<!Fragment>
#version 150
/// code here!

void main()
{
/// code here!
}
<Fragment!>
```

EDIT 2:  here is a better example of what needs to work:

[regex editor](https://regex101.com/r/pK9bO0/2)

I did quite some combinations already but the most logical that came to mind is this one:

```
std::smatch u;
std::string s = shader->GetData();
std::regex_match(s, u, std::regex("<.*>(.*)<!.*>"));
```

I'm having no luck yet and I'm wondering if anyone would have an idea on what the syntax might be?!

thx

Comment: The <, >, and ! are special to regex.  You need to escape them.  The escape character is \ which is special to C strings, you need to escape them too, so try "\\<[^>]*\\>(.*)\\<\\![^>]\\>" - I don't have a way to test it right now though

Comment: I'm guessing one * was missing and I tried this as well as your suggestion:

"\\<[^>]*\\>(.*)\\<\\![^>]*\\>"

No luck so far. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Instead of escaping, you may use raw string literals, like `std::regex(R"delim(<.*>(.*)<!.*>)delim")`. See [#6 here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) or https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/10/16/cpp-11-raw-strings-literals-tutorial/.

Comment: thank you vsoftco, it's noted.

Comment: are you sure you want to use regex_match, maybe regex_search is more appropriate?  match must match the entire target

Comment: I'll definitely consider any viable solution. Still not sure how regex_search would extract the data in between the tags though.

Comment: My researches are telling me that ".*" will match any single character other than a newline. So my test case is not going to work for sure. Would Les suggestion using [^>] match any single characters including new lines as well?

Comment: right, .* will not match \n ... change (.*) to ([^<]*)

Comment: thank you for your support everyone, it seems like we're getting closer and here is what we have so far:

"\\<[^>]*\\>([^<]*)\\<\\![^>]*\\>"

no luck yet but I'm still digging.

Comment: try this expression... "([<][^>]*[>]([^<]*)[<][!][^>]*[>][^<]*)+"

Comment: I am using [<] instead of \\<, same thing

Comment: So far the best result is with search:

std::regex_search(s, u, std::regex("\\<[^>]*\\>([^<]*)\\<\\![^>]*\\>"));

the only problem is that it works for files that have only one begin and end tags. Need a way to say "for every" begin and end tags. If possible.

Comment: Might help to say that I'm parsing GLSL shaders and the example case is rather simplified compared to actual work. Regarding the previous post, it seems it is only grabbing one hit so the next "begin and end tags" are ignored. Some file are also ignored completely. So I'll need to dig even further as comments and all kinds of special characters are into the shader data.

Answer (score 0):

If your tags are tidy, you can try something like this: `(?:<[^<>!]*?>\n?)((.|\n)*?)(?:<!.*>(\n|$)?)`

Needs to be escaped accordingly to C, of course: `(?:\\<[^<>!]*?\\>\\n?)((.|\\n)*?)(?:\\<!.*\\>(\\n|$)?)`

The code itself being the capture group $1

https://regex101.com/r/vC5xD3/2 (it's php, but the idea remains).

Answer (score 0):

Consider regex_search instead.  You can then access each of your sub matches.  Here is an example that you might be able to start with...

```
std::smatch u;
std::string s = "<Sometag>\n// Lots of code here! (Multiline)\n<!Sometag>\n\n<Sometag2>\n// Lots of code here! (Multiline)\n<!Sometag2>\n";
std::regex e("<[^>]*>([^<]*)<[!][^>]*>[^<]*");
std::cmatch m;

while (s.length() > 0)
{
    bool result = std::regex_search(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), u, e);
    if (result == false)
        break;
    for (std::smatch::iterator it = u.begin(); it != u.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
    s = u.suffix();
}
```

*EDIT*
The following expression is more tolerant of < within the code.

```
std::regex e("^<([^>]*)>(((.|\\n)*)<[!]\\1>[^<]*)?");
```

There are more sub-matches this way, but one of them will be the contents between the tags.

**EDIT 2**
Based on the better example string you provide, here is another code example that breaks the target string down into sub matches.  The 4th sub-match is the actual content of the tags

```
std::smatch u;
std::string s = "/// Comments.\r\n\r\n<!Vertex>\r\n#version 150\r\n\r\n//#define DISPLAY_DIFFUSE 0\r\n//#define DISPLAY_BUMP 1\r\n//#define DISPLAY_SPECULAR 2\r\n//#define ... \r\n\r\n<Vertex!>\r\n\r\n/// Comments.\r\n\r\n<!Fragment>\r\n#version 150\r\n\r\n//#define DISPLAY_DIFFUSE 0\r\n//#define DISPLAY_BUMP 1\r\n//#define DISPLAY_SPECULAR 2\r\n//#define ... \r\n\r\n<Fragment!>\r\n\r\n";
std::regex e("<[!]([^>]*)>");  //to skip to the first tag
std::cmatch m;

// search to the first tag
bool result = std::regex_search(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), u, e);
if (result == true)
{   // skip characters before first tag
    s = s.substr(u.prefix().length());

    // regex to find <!tag>...<tag!>... capturing several things
    // fourth sub-string is the content between the tags
    e = std::regex("^<[!]([^>]*)>(((.|[\\n\\r])*)<\\1[!]>[^<]*)");
    while (s.length() > 0)
    {
        // find a tag and its contents
        result = std::regex_search(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), u, e);
        if (result == false)
            break;
        // interate through the sub-matches (the 4th is the
        // contents between tags
        int idx = 0;
        for (std::smatch::iterator it = u.begin(); it != u.end(); ++it)
        {
            if(++idx == 4)
                std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        }
        s = u.suffix();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good plan. The data I'm parsing as code in it so the < and > is causing a lot of issues that I'm trying to figure. Still digging.

Comment: so basically the code has potentially < and > in it so I changed the tags to:
start <!Sometag>
end  <Sometag!>

also there could be text before the first tag like so:

/// Comments.
<!Sometag>
/// code
<Sometag!>
/// More Comments.
<!Sometag>
/// code
<Sometag!>
/// Still comments.

Comment: Alright, got it.

"<[!][^>]*>([^<][^!]*)<[^>]*[!]>"

Thank you everyone for helping out. It was more challenging than expected.

Comment: Apparently, I've been lucky because I'm not quite there yet. This is causing me issue on some shaders that use < and !:

([^<][^!]*)

I'm trying to find the proper syntax to say, everything but stop at <!
Been pulling my hair out.

Comment: I don't think you mean [^<][^!]*, I think you need a lookahead or lookbehind

Comment: Each attempt fails on my side: here is what the code might look like:

s = "/// Comments.\r\n\r\n<!Vertex>\r\n#version 150\r\n\r\n//#define DISPLAY_DIFFUSE 0\r\n//#define DISPLAY_BUMP 1\r\n//#define DISPLAY_SPECULAR 2\r\n//#define ...
\r\n\r\n<Vertex!>\r\n\r\n/// Comments.\r\n\r\n<!Fragment>\r\n#version 150\r\n\r\n//#define DISPLAY_DIFFUSE 0\r\n//#define DISPLAY_BUMP 1\r\n//#define DISPLAY_SPECULAR 2\r\n//#define ...
\r\n\r\n<Fragment!>\r\n\r\n

might need to add more to (((.|\\n)*) but I'm having no successful combination yet. thank again for your inputs. Still digging.

Comment: well, your tags don't agree with your original post, <!tag>...<tag!> is more like it (not <tag>...<!tag>)

Comment: Hello Les, thank you very much for your insights. Unfortunately, the content of the shaders can reach up to 1000s of lines of code and might use all kinds of combination of !, <,> and I can’t get pass the search without crashing. I didn’t expect this would take so much time to figure it out when all that is really needed is this:

<[!]\\S+>
(*)
<\\S+[!]>

Do you have another trick under your sleeve that could somehow simplify this process?

Comment: Sorry about the tag format changing, I'm trying all kind of ideas. this is what I'm trying right now:
`<[!]\\S+>([^]*)<\\S+[!]>` seems like a good start but for some reason, if 2 shaders are in the same file it return between the first opening tag and the second closing tag. Any ideas how to make sure both shaders are return?