# c++ regex - everything but a charcater sequence?

Tags: c++, regex

I'm looking for a way to extract everything before those two character `<!`. And I do not want not < and/or ! like `([^<][^!]*)`, I want not `<!` but I cant find any combinations that seems to work with regex_search or regex_match.

```
([^<!]*) // not working for me
([^[<!]]*) // not working for me
([^<^!]*) // not working for me
```

nor any combination with escaping as well like

```
(^[\\<\\!]*)
```

Keep in mind that the text before can contain any possible combination of < and ! but never both next to each other. what am I missing?

EDIT: I realize I'm forking this question as I was actually looking to understand the not character sequence here but I think this example might help anyways.

[Real time work edit](https://regex101.com/r/pK9bO0/3)

EDIT 2: I finally get the editor to work here:

[Real time work edit 2](https://regex101.com/r/pK9bO0/3)

Which should transpose to:

```
std::string s = l_shader->GetData();
std::smatch u;

std::regex_search(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), u, std::regex("<(\\S+)[!]>([\\s\\S]*?)(?=<!)"));
```

But returns no valid hit with Visual Studio 2013 rc5. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30928091?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++11 regex extracting text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928091/c11-regex-extracting-text)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
(.*?)<!
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK9bO0/1)**

I'm not sure if C++ supports lookarounds but you could also use:

```
(.*?)(?=<!)
```

Comment: Hi Fede, the problem with this approach is that it doesn't grab multilines

Comment: @neosettler that's pretty simple to fix, just change `(.*?)` by `([\s\S]*?)`

Comment: Hi Fede, thank you for your feedback, I made an edit to the original question based on your suggestions. I'm afraid I did ask poorly but the example should be self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
([^<]!|<[^!]|[^<!])*
```

Note that the order of the alternatives is important, as they're tested in order.

There's still one minor caveat that it'll also return empty matches between any instances of `<!`, but I expect it should be easy to detect this. Or you could avoid it by always making sure to start the match at (or after?) the `!`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. It does work but for one iteration only. did you look at the Real time work edit here! ? In this case, it should return 2 times, all the content inside the begin and end tags.

Comment: I did look at the real time work edit. If you mean it only finds the first match, the problem is that that site is using JavaScript, so you need to add the `g` flag to the second field to make it return _all_ matches. If you're using `std::regex` in C++, if I recall correctly you can either use a `std::regex_iterator` to iterate through all matches, or pass in a start index to start the search from that point (you'd pass in where the match last ended).

Comment: Oh yes indeed. I've put the g and use `([^<]!|<[^!]|[^<!])*` but I do not get a successful result in the editor. still digging.